# How to get RGB values of every pixel in BMP by using Qt?

Tags: qt, bmp, compression

I need to write simple program which can open any BMP file, use RLE compression, save result, open it again and decompress file to normal BMP. 
Problem is I do not know how to get RGB components of file. There are so many version of BMP standard. 
I know how to open it in Qt, how to create, and how load in to widget, but I can not find a way to read file information and headers in one bytearray and RGB values in another. Is there in Qt some methods to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`QImage`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimage.html) will load the image for you. BMP is one of the [supported formats](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files). You shouldn't care about the BMP standard used since `Qt` handles it internally.

You can access the RGB value of any pixel using the [`pixel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimage.html#pixel-2) method of `QImage`.

```
QImage image;
image.load("myimage.bmp");
QVector<QRgb> imageRGBValues;

for (unsigned i=0; i<image.width(); ++i)
{
   for (unsigned j=0; j<image.height(); ++j)
      imageRGBValues.push_back(image.pixel(i,j));
}
```